# How can I get these array values to all print into an html form?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, operators

I have a small piece of code that generates an array with values based on a triangle. I will post the array below.

```
var endwallPanelLengths = [totalHeightInches];
var i = 0;
while (endwallPanelLengths[i] > eaveInches) 
{
    endwallPanelLengths.push(endwallPanelLengths[i] - peakHeightDecrease);
    document.getElementById("test83").value="4 - " + endwallPanelLengths[i];
    i++;
}
```

This array will have anywhere between 2 to 100 indexes. I want the code to write all of the values separated by breaks into a `<textarea>` with the id="test83".
If I run the code as it is set up above it will only write the value in array [1] not [0] or any of the others. How can I get it to write all of them so that they come out looking like this...

4 - 140   this is the value of array position [0]

4 - 126

4 - 116   and so on?

Comment: yes that number will represent the highest point of the triangle, when I run this code it starts writing at array [1]

Comment: What does your html look like? It seems like you'll just be over writing your value each time.

Comment: In the <textarea> with the id that I am writing to I only see 4 - 126 which is the second index of the array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You keep replacing the value

```
document.getElementById("test83").value="4 - " + endwallPanelLengths[i];
```

You would need to append to the value

```
document.getElementById("test83").value += "4 - " + endwallPanelLengths[i] + "\n";
```

better yet, build up the values and set the value once

```
var endwallPanelLengths = [totalHeightInches],
    i = 0,
    output = [];
while (endwallPanelLengths[i] > eaveInches) 
{
    endwallPanelLengths.push(endwallPanelLengths[i] - peakHeightDecrease);
    output.push("4 - " + endwallPanelLengths[i]);
    i++;
}
document.getElementById("test83").value = output.join("\n");
```

Comment: This example is working however it is only giving me the first to index positions and not the third

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding you correctly, that you want the array displayed with one item per line in your `textarea`, then you should be able to ditch your loop completely, and just do it in one shot.

```
document.getElementById("test83").value = endwallPanelLengths.join('\n');
```

Although it also looks like you're prepending '4 -' to each value.  If that's the case, then you could just add one extra step to get those fours added:

```
var arr = endwallPanelLengths.map(function(item){ return '4 - ' + item; });
document.getElementById("test83").value = arr.join('\n');
```

Just be sure to grab the shim for `Array.prototype.map` from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) if you need to support IE8

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div id="holder"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var endwallPanelLengths = [totalHeightInches];
var i = 0;
var holder =  document.getElementById("holder");
while (endwallPanelLengths[i] > eaveInches) 
{
    endwallPanelLengths.push(endwallPanelLengths[i] - peakHeightDecrease);
    var e = document.createElement('div');
    e.innerHTML = "4 - " + endwallPanelLengths[i] + "<br />";
    holder.appendChild(e.firstChild);
    i++;
}
```

Hopefully that does for you what you want. In your example, in your loop, you're setting the newest value to the same element, thus overwriting any previous values.

Comment: you are appending to a textarea?